Hide columns if all values are null or zero
The goal I'm trying to achieve is to hide a column if all its values ​​result in null or null.
  CREATE TABLE m_value_tbl  (net_value, net_con,total_net) AS 
  SELECT   cast(NULL as number), cast(0 as number), cast(NULL as number) FROM DUAL 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT   cast(NULL as number),  cast(2 as number), cast(NULL as number) FROM DUAL ;

The expected result is:
            net_value net_con   total_net
             null      2            null

What I tried is the following:
       SELECT
          net_value
         ,net_con
         ,TOTAL_NET
      from m_value_tbl
       where
      (net_value IS NOT NULL
      OR net_con IS NOT NULL
      OR total_net IS NOT NULL)


Completely hiding an entire column from a result set would require using dynamic SQL...it cannot be done simply using query syntax.  Typically, this is something you would handle in the presentation layer.

Can you give me more detail on this.
Tim Biegeleisen

Your description and example don't match. You say you want to hide columns, but in your expected result you show all columns, but only one of two rows. The dismissed row doesn't only have null values either, so if this is about dismissing rows instead of columns where all values are null, this doesn't match either. Please edit your request and clarify this.

This request seems completely messed up. You say you want to dismiss columns from your results where all values are null. But according to the desired result shown it rather seems you want to dismiss all rows from your result where all values are either null or zero.
In your query you select all rows where at least one of the columns is not null (by using OR):
WHERE net_value IS NOT NULL
   OR net_con   IS NOT NULL
   OR total_net IS NOT NULL

What you want instead is where all columns match your condition (by using AND), i.e.:
WHERE net_value IS NOT NULL
  AND net_con   IS NOT NULL
  AND total_net IS NOT NULL

As your condition seems to be that all columns must neither be null nor zero, you can use WHERE .. IS NOT NULL AND .. <> 0, which can be simplified to WHERE .. <> 0, as NULL can never equal or unequal a value.
SELECT
  net_value,
  net_con,
  total_net
FROM m_value_tbl    
WHERE net_value <> 0
  AND net_con   <> 0
  AND total_net <> 0;


You cannot do that using SQL.
If you want to hide columns then this should be done in the programming language that you are calling the database from (i.e. Java, PHP, C#, Python, etc.) as SQL (in any dialect, not just Oracle) and the client applictions that pass SQL queries to the database (SQL*Plus, SQL Developer, TOAD, etc.) do not support conditionally displaying columns based on results.

If you want to do it using PL/SQL then something like:
DECLARE
  v_cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
  v_cnt PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(total_net) INTO v_cnt FROM m_value_tbl;

  IF v_cnt > 0 THEN
    OPEN v_cur FOR
      SELECT net_value, net_con, total_net FROM m_value_tbl;
  ELSE
    OPEN v_cur FOR
      SELECT net_value, net_con FROM m_value_tbl;
  END IF;

  DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(v_cur);
END;
/

